# Confusion with Win32 Connections - Why does this code work?

Tags: c++, winapi

I followed a tutorial on some win32, creation and interaction, but I'm not sure how the code connects a "Write here" edit box to a message box.

```
#define IDC_MAIN_BUTTON 101         // Button identifier
#define IDC_MAIN_EDIT   102         // Edit box identifier
HWND hEdit;

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT message,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE hPrevInst,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nShowCmd)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wClass;
    ZeroMemory(&wClass,sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
    wClass.cbClsExtra=NULL;
    wClass.cbSize=sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wClass.cbWndExtra=NULL;
    wClass.hbrBackground=(HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wClass.hCursor=LoadCursor(NULL,IDC_ARROW);
    wClass.hIcon=NULL;
    wClass.hIconSm=NULL;
    wClass.hInstance=hInst;
    wClass.lpfnWndProc=(WNDPROC)WinProc;
    wClass.lpszClassName="Window Class";
    wClass.lpszMenuName=NULL;
    wClass.style=CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW;

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wClass))
    {
        int nResult=GetLastError();
        MessageBox(NULL,
            "Window class creation failed\r\n",
            "Window Class Failed",
            MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    HWND hWnd=CreateWindowEx(NULL,
            "Window Class",
            "Windows application",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            200,
            200,
            640,
            480,
            NULL,
            NULL,
            hInst,
            NULL);

    if(!hWnd)
    {
        int nResult=GetLastError();

        MessageBox(NULL,
            "Window creation failed\r\n",
            "Window Creation Failed",
            MB_ICONERROR);
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd,nShowCmd);

    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg,sizeof(MSG));

    while(GetMessage(&msg,NULL,0,0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
        {

// How does this edit box, connect to the button?

            // Create an edit box
            hEdit=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                "EDIT",
                "",
                WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|
                ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|ES_AUTOHSCROLL,
                50,
                100,
                200,
                100,8
                hWnd,
                (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_EDIT, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
            HGDIOBJ hfDefault=GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
            SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfDefault, MAKELPARAM(FALSE,0));
            SendMessage(hEdit, WM_SETTEXT, NULL, (LPARAM)"Insert text here...");

            // Create a push button
            HWND hWndButton=CreateWindowEx(NULL,
                "BUTTON",
                "OK",
                WS_TABSTOP|WS_VISIBLE|
                WS_CHILD|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,
                50,
                220,
                100,
                24,
                hWnd,
                (HMENU)IDC_MAIN_BUTTON, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
            SendMessage(hWndButton, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfDefault, MAKELPARAM(FALSE,0));
        }
        break;



        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case IDC_MAIN_BUTTON:
                {
                    char buffer[256];
                    SendMessage(hEdit, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]), reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(buffer));
                    MessageBox(NULL, buffer, "Information", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
                }
                break;
            }
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
}
```

I am really not sure how the text box sends its info to the message box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is these three lines:

```
char buffer[256];
SendMessage(hEdit, WM_GETTEXT, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(buffer[0]), reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(buffer));
MessageBox(NULL, buffer, "Information", MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

The `WM_GETTEXT` message does the following:

> Copies the text that corresponds to a window into a buffer provided by the caller.

So the first call `SendMessage` will copy what's in the `hEdit` window to the `buffer` you created the line before.

Then the next line writes the contents of `buffer` to the `MessageBox`

Comment: Thank you, I understand it a bit better, but I will go through some more WINAPI tutorials!

Answer (score 1):

When you do `CreateWindowEx`, it creates a message queue. Then anyone can send message to this window using its handle.

While `CreateWindowEx()` you are giving id `IDC_MAIN_EDIT`. So when you press button this will be send as a command to your **window-message-Queue**. This is handled in your `proc()` case `IDC_MAIN_EDIT`:.

Answer (score 0):

The textbox doesn't "send its info".  When the button is clicked, the case `WM_COMMAND` runs and it gets the content from the textbox.  That's the `SendMessage(..., WM_GETTEXT, ...)` call.